# IE10 Windows7 -- Audio tag never plays audio?

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-10

I'm having problems with the audio tag in IE10/Windows 7.  I found this [test page](http://textopia.org/androidsoundformats.html) and wonderfully, IE cannot display ANY audio tag. The funny thing is when I save the file and test it locally, it works perfectly (image below)

[image]

I checked the mime types on all of the files, and it appears that they're all correct:

[image: mime]

Next up was to check my media definitions in preferences:

[image: preferences]

What the heck?  Any ideas here?

Comment: I put a bounty up on a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312488/error-unsupported-audio-type-or-invalid-file-path-for-html5-audio-tag-in-inte?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a problem with that particular page. I can reproduce the error here on a test machine I have. (Server 2012)

Edit - Just found this:

[HTML5 audio element do not work in IE10, but works in Chrome. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339291/html5-audio-element-do-not-work-in-ie10-but-works-in-chrome-why)

**Edit 2:** Seems to be permissions based. Right-clicking and selecting run as administrator allows the audio to load.

Comment: I don't think so, this is happening to me, after googling around I found that test page -- funny enough, it works locally (changed the image)

Comment: I saved it locally and opened it and it still won't load correctly. Very strange.

Comment: Im stumped. Can't get it to work over here at all. Must be a problem with that browser.

Comment: I think so ... I found: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/32495/ie10-update-has-broken-jw-player/

Comment: Have you tried right clicking and running IE as administrator? Maybe permissions?

Comment: Microsoft man.. what are they doing over there. At least you have a work around.. heh.

Comment: this has to be the most screwed up thing ever -- after rebooting and re-opening ie in non-administrator mode, it runs fine afterwards.

Comment: I don't understand things like that. Drives me crazy.

Comment: must've been a windows update that wouldn't unpack without admin permissions I'm guessing.  I wonder how many users this affects ......

Answer (score -1):

Problem is your Internet Explorer Cache Folder, check Settings for Temporary Internet Files, i had same Problem it displayed no Folder and Folder size of 0 on my machine.

Move it to c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows